# Simple Integration Question - Integral of the product of a function and its derivative.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Why does $\int y'(x) y(x) dx = y(x)^2/2 + C$? This seems to be true, at least according to Wolfram, but I do not understand how it is derived.

Comment: Substitute $u=y(x)$ to get $\int u du$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of $dy(x)$; this is $y^\prime(x)dx$. So, we can simplify $y^\prime(x)dx$ in the integral to $dy(x)$. Can you integrate:
$$\int y(x)dy(x)?$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The derivative of $y(x)^2$ is, by the Chain Rule, $2y(x)y'(x)$.